# Bash recursively append one file to another

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash function to automate a bunch of actions when setting up a new project. Below is an example directory structure. I have two projects and some template files and codepieces.

```
~/projects
├── template_files/
│   ├── folder_A1/
│   ├── file_A2
│   └── ...
│
├── codepieces/
│   ├── file_X
│   └── ...
│
├── project1/
│   ├── file_X
│   └── ...
│
├── project2/
│   ├── file_X
│   └── ...
```

One of the actions in my bash function copies (adds/overwrites) the entire template_files structure into a project.

`$ cp -a template-files/. projectX`

I would like to do the same for my codepieces, except instead of adding or replacing, I'd like to append the content to existing files (without doing this one by one as `$ echo codepieces/file_X >> projectX/file_x` would.

So I'm looking for something that combines the functionalities `$ cp -a` with `$ echo codepieces/file_X >> projectX/file_x`. The result for project1 would be like so:

```
~/project1
├── folder_A1/
├── file_A2
├── file_X (original code is appended with codepiece)
└── ...
```

Comment: I've never heard of anything that does this, you'll probably need to write a script to do it. `rsync` has lots of options, but it doesn't do this (there's a `--append` option, but it's different).

Answer (score 0):

A simple bash function you can tweak to your criteria:

```
cp-a_with-append(){
    if [ ! -d "$1" ] || [ ! -d "$2" ]; then
        echo 1>&2 Usage: cp-a_with_append SRCDIR DESTDIR
    else
        ( cd "$1" && find ) | while read p; do
            pin="$1/$p"
            pout="$2/$p"
            # [ -d "$pin" ] && mkdir -p "$pout"
            [ -f "$pin" ] && [ -f "$pout" ] && cat "$pin" >> "$pout"
            touch -cr "$pin" "$pout"
        done
    fi
}
```